# Base class reference in Scala

Tags: scala

I have to store a set of shape classes (say squares and circles) in a single array/set in scala.

In C++, we can store pointers to objects of derived class in a base class pointer.

```
std::vector<shape*> list;
shape* temp = new square;
list.push_back(temp);
```

Is such a thing possible in Scala? If so how does that code look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, as in Java, array and list does not store actual elements, they only store **references** to actual elements(non primitives). That means you can do same thing with arrays.

Java arrays do store some actual elements of **primitive** data types. Scala 2.8+ has **@specialized** feature which prevents from boxing of "primitives"

Comment: Except for arrays of primitive types, and for specialized types in Scala, which do store actual elements.

Comment: Can u give examples of this specialized types? I didn't know that

Comment: http://www.scala-notes.org/2011/04/specializing-for-primitive-types/ (Note there are quite a few limitations involved)

Answer (score 4):

Scala is an OO language, so why would that be a problem?

```
trait Shape
case class Square(x: Int, y: Int, w: Int, h: Int) extends Shape

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val list = new ArrayBuffer[Shape]
list += new Square(0,0,10,10)
```